# Which order to paint ceiling and replace downlights?

Tags: paint, recessed-lighting

Which order should I do these two tasks:

- repaint ceiling
- replace downlights (licenced electrician will do this)

The downlights are recessed and the whole thing will be replaced (not just the bulb).

Comment: What sort of new downlights?   Cans or the newer LED types that clip to the sheetrock?  If cans, it's most common to install them first, then paint, then install the trim rings and bulbs.  If "clip-on" types, the electrician will probably place them in the sheetrock where you want them.   BTW, why are you replacing the entire recessed assembly?  There are some decent retrofits (LED) that are easy to install and look great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most cases you want to

1. Remove the old fixtures (or at least the bulb portion). These typically have a flange that covers the ugly hole in the drywall
2. Paint
3. Replace fixtures

If you do it this way, you can paint around the hole itself and then the fixture will hide it. Painting around fixtures is a pain, and you're making more work doing in in any other order.

Comment: And you run the risk of the new fixtures being smaller leaving an old paint circle... more of an issue with surface mount...